netfilter, how to get MAC by NFQA_HWADDR or ()L2HW) using netfilter queue?
I have tried to get some minimal knowledge of the netf queue. So, first at all I try to "capture" ICMP packets:
nft add rule ip filter OUTPUT ip protocol icmp counter queue num 1

But question: is how to retrieve hardware src ?

Can you post your code?

I got an answer from NETFILTER community : there is no way to get MAC for destination\src.

Please check nfq_get_packet_hw();
static uint32_t print_pkt (struct nfq_data *tb)
{
    int id = 0;
    struct nfqnl_msg_packet_hdr *ph;
    struct nfqnl_msg_packet_hw *hwph;
    uint32_t mark, ifi, uid, gid;
    int ret;
    unsigned char *data, *secdata;
    ph = nfq_get_msg_packet_hdr(tb);

    if (ph) {
        id = ntohl(ph->packet_id);
        printf("hw_protocol=0x%04x hook=%u id=%u ",
            ntohs(ph->hw_protocol), ph->hook, id);
    }
    
    hwph = nfq_get_packet_hw(tb);
    if (hwph) {
        int i, hlen = ntohs(hwph->hw_addrlen);
            printf("hw_src_addr=");
        for (i = 0; i < hlen-1; i++)
            printf("%02x:", hwph->hw_addr[i]);
        printf("%02x ", hwph->hw_addr[hlen-1]);
    }
}       

Source of above snippet: libnetfilter_queue/src/utils/nfqnl_test.c
